# How to select upcoming dates from mysql from following date format?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, date

How to select upcoming date?

```
datetime
01/24/2020 6:15 PM,
01/39/1994 12:04 AM,
01/29/1994 12:04 AM,
01/30/2020 6:15 PM,
07/19/1994 12:04 AM
```

[image: data]

Comment: What is your question: do you want to turn these strings to dates?

Comment: I want to select upcoming date from this string.

Comment: convert them to date first and then choose the upcoming dates using a  simple WHERE clause: `WHERE datetime>Today` I don't know the MySQL syntax so find the proper syntax yourself

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to turn these strings to dates? You can use `str_to_date()` for this:

```
str_to_date(mycol, '%m/%d/%Y %k:%i %p')
```

Once this is done, you can filter on future dates like so:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where str_to_date(mycol, '%m/%d/%Y %k:%i %p') > current_timestamp
```

Note that this is an unefficient method: the database needs to convert each and every string to a date before being able to compare it (an index is of no use here).

As a priority, you should consider fixing your data model to store dates in the relevant datatype (MySQL has `datetime` or `timestamp`).

Comment: Just for info what would look out put of this code ?